# Failed to add FK in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have Report class

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord
end
```

and 2 derived class Coachingreport and MedicalReport

```
class MedicalReport < Report
end

class CoachingReport < Report
end
```

And also Player class

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
end
```

I want to create one to many realation such that reports tables will hold player id. However when I add relation to Report class tables created form subclasses do not have their columns, only ones from Report class. But when I add relation specifically to each subclasses created table have all columns but player_id.

Comment: What do you mean "do not have their columns"? These Objects inherit from Report and will be stored in the "reports" table, generally speaking one would add a `type` column to this table and this would be referred to as Single Table Inheritance (STI) [Docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html). If these Objects are intended to be backed by separate tables then you will need to redesign the application to support this. How you go about this is dependent on your desired outcome and cannot be inferred from the question at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Your classes need to declare the relationships, otherwise none of this will work.

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :player
end

class Player < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reports
end
```

If migrations are working, you should have a reports table and a players table, where the reports table has a `player_id`.

The Report subclasses will still be using reports table. The reports table will need a `type` field to differentiate them. [Reference](https://medium.com/@GeneHFang/single-table-inheritance-in-rails-6-emulating-oop-principles-in-relational-databases-be60c84e0126).

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tried to do that before however as I mentioned the columns for MedicalReport and CoachingReport are not created apart form those inherited from Report

Comment: Do you think that order of creating relations and migrations can influence this matter?